# Is product NM positive definite when N is a diagonal positive definite matrix and M is an asymmetric positive definite matrix

Tags: matrices

I have the following question:

Matrix $N$ is a diagonal matrix with all entries strictly positive (hence, $N$ is positive definite since it satisfies $x^T N x > 0$). Matrix $M$ is an asymmetric positive definite matrix with all entries non-negative.

Since $NM \neq MN$, it does not follow that the product $NM$ is positive definite. However, given the special structure of $N$, can we still show that $NM$ is positive definite? Or maybe, under certain additional conditions?

Comment: What do you mean by positive definite for an asymmetric matrix? There are different options.

Comment: I meant that M also satisfies $x^T M x > 0$.

Answer (score 3):

It's not true in general: take
$$
N=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1/5\end{bmatrix},\ \ \ M=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}.
$$
$M$ is positive-definite according to your definition, since
$$
\begin{bmatrix}x\\ y\end{bmatrix}^TM\begin{bmatrix}x\\ y\end{bmatrix}=x^2+xy+y^2>0
$$
on nonzero vectors.

On the other hand
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1\\-2\end{bmatrix}^TNM\begin{bmatrix}1\\-2\end{bmatrix}=-\frac15.
$$

As for conditions, of course one can force $M$ to be trivial enough for the property to hold; but I'll be surprised if there is a meaningful condition on $M$ that guarantees that $NM$ is positive-definite.

Comment: Yes, it does look like that. Thanks for your response!

Comment: Would the result hold if $M$ is also symmetric?

Comment: No. $\ \ \ \ \ $

Comment: The following fact might be helpful. If both $M$ and $N$ are symmetric and p.d., and furthermore, $MN=NM$ (i.e., symmetric), then $MN$ must be p.d. as well.